# How to let users increase font-size by clicking the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to figure how to create an idea I had the other day for awhile now and can't seem to get it to work due to being a bit of noob still.

Anyway, to the point, I am trying to create as the title says, a paragraph where the user can simply click on the text / paragraph and have the font size increase each time.

I was able to get a working form where I could put in a multiple choice box and have the users change size with that, but that simply isn't what I want to do..

I was thinking it would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
do
    {
    if (user-clicks) increase font size;
    else keep current font size;    
    }
while (font-size < 4em)
</script>
```

Can anyone more experienced please help me getting this to work or at least put me on a path where I can more successfully figure it out myself? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function resizeText(multiplier) {
    multiplyText(multiplier, document.getElementById('myContent'));    
}

function multiplyText(multiplier, txtobj) {
    //keep current font size
    if (txtobj.style.fontSize == '') {
        txtobj.style.fontSize = "100%";
    }
    //keep current font size
    if (multiplier == 0) {
        txtobj.style.fontSize = "100%";
    } 
    else { //get only the number part of the fontsize
    txtobj.style.fontSize = parseFloat(txtobj.style.fontSize) + multiplier + "%";
    }
}


</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="myContent">
 <a href="javascript:resizeText(10);"> Increase font</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: call with javascript:resizeText(0) to keep the current font and call with javascript:resizeText(-10) to reduce font

Comment: userDEV, you are amazing, thank you so much. Could you explain a few parts of it though, please? I would very much like to learn this for myself rather than completely rip-off your code, haha. Mostly what is the 'tabindex="15" accesskey="N"' for and maybe explain parseFloat or any other part / just add general documentation? If you can't / won't though it's no problem, you helped immensely, thank you very much regardless. :)

Comment: tabindex and accesskey can be deleted.  They are html attributes used when on a form.  If you're in the first field of a form then hit tab, you automatically move to the next field.  This the code above is the 15th field from a from of a pre-existing custom page on my site.  Acceskey is like creating a shortcut key on a page.  Again this was on my custom page which will probably not be needed for your page.  If you hit Alt + N key, while on the form page, it will automatically bring focus to the link.  I hope this make sense.  I will add comments to the js code to define parsefloat.  Thx

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you very much; You have been a lot of help

Answer (score 0):

Working Code with JQuery:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var gFont=1;
    $('.fontAuto').click(function(e) {
        if(gFont<4){
                gFont=gFont+0.5;
        $('.fontAuto').css('font-size',gFont+'em');
        }else{
            gFont =1;
            $('.fontAuto').css('font-size','1em');
        }
    });

    });
    </script>
    <style type='text/css'>

    .fontAuto{
        font-size:1em;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p class="fontAuto">Text For testing</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving you a very **short & simple** answer-

```
<p id=p1 style="font-size:25">
    click <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('p1').style.fontSize=50">here</a> to enlarge.
</p>
```

In case you want to do it on click at any part of the `<p>...</p>` tag use-

```
<p id=p1 style="font-size:25" onclick="this.style.fontSize=50">
    click to enlarge.
</p>
```

### Customize it as you wish.